# toggle nearest element after, but outside of current class

Tags: jquery

Here i want to hide msg_wrap div which is nearest (after) to clicked msg_head class. My jquery:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".msg_head", function() {
  $(this).closest('.msg_wrap').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msg_head" id="c_name_msgHead">
  <div class="close">x</div>
</div>

<div class="msg_wrap">wrap
</div>

<div class="msg_head" id="c_name_msgHead">
  <div class="close">x</div>
</div>

<div class="msg_wrap">wrap
</div>
```

But it is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks up the ancestor tree:

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

What you need is [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".msg_head", function() {
  $(this).next('.msg_wrap').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msg_head" id="c_name_msgHead">
  <div class="close">x</div>
</div>

<div class="msg_wrap">wrap
</div>

<div class="msg_head" id="c_name_msgHead">
  <div class="close">x</div>
</div>

<div class="msg_wrap">wrap
</div>
```

Comment: @Pekka no problem :-)

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan - when you accept an answer, you get positive reputation. You should make it a habit :-)

Comment: I always do that. I gave your answer up vote and additionally let you know my pleasure to be helped. :)